# Docker/GitLab: npm dependencies installed in docker image, but unmet via runner

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, gitlab

First of all I'm checking the testing docker image, which I'm using as a docker runner in my gitlab CI:

Running this command inside if the docker container (`testing`)...

```
meteor npm list --depth=0
```

gives me the expeceted result:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.4.2
npm info using node@v8.6.0
project@1.0.0 /builds/namespace/project
+-- autoprefixer@7.1.5
+-- babel-runtime@6.26.0
+-- bcrypt@1.0.3
+-- fluent-ffmpeg@2.1.2
+-- gm@1.23.0
+-- gridfs-stream@1.1.1
+-- react@16.0.0
```

So all dependencies are installed in the docker image. Now I'm using this image in my gitLab CI:

My gitLab CI yml file looks like this:

```
unit:
  image: testing:latest
  stage: unit
  tags:
    - testing
  script:
    - meteor npm list --depth=0
```

But the result is:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.4.2
npm info using node@v8.6.0
project@1.0.0 /builds/namespace/project
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY autoprefixer@7.1.4
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY babel-runtime@6.26.0
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY bcrypt@1.0.3
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY fluent-ffmpeg@2.1.2
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY gm@1.23.0
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY gridfs-stream@1.1.1
+-- UNMET DEPENDENCY react@15.6.0
```

Why are the dependencies not installed? I don't want to install them each time the CI is running the job. Instead I want all dependecies already installed in the docker image to get it faster.

**Update**

Running the CI stage, there is no `node_modules` directory, which is existing in the docker image...
How do I prevent gitlab to remove the folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the build starts it fetches your repo again essentially overwriting the contents with a fresh clone. The quickest fix is to temporarily move the dependencies to a different folder then move them back during the actual build. For example perform the `meteor npm install`  move the `node_modules`  to  `/example/node_modules` then during the build move them back to `/builds/namespace/project/node_modules`